# Can .nomedia be a folder?

Tags: media-scanner

If a file called `.nomedia` gets put into a directory, the Media Scanner skips that directory, e.g. sprite images.

Does that also work if `.nomedia` is a folder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. If a folder contains another folder that is named `.nomedia`, the parent folder will be ignored.

The relevant code is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/media/java/android/media/MediaScanner.java#1416) (note to the confused: `File` doesn't necessarily be a regular file - in Linux directories are just special files).

One of my favorite IME app also creates folders of this name (instead of files) in its asset folders - the assets are ignored by MediaScanner.

Trivia: If you managed to put other special files like symbolic links or named pipes (FIFOs) with the name `.nomedia`, it will also work. (Spoiler: indeed you can, but you need root).

An alternative way, as suggested by beeshyams, is to rename the parent folder and make it start with a dot. This has the same effect as having a `.nomedia` inside it, as both ways make the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/media/java/android/media/MediaScanner.java#1407) return true (should be ignored).

Comment: +1. i didn't know that  !

Comment: I don't think the "note to the confused" is especially un-confusing. `java.io.File` is not Android or Linux specific, and can just represent any pathname, including a directory name, on any system, eg. on Windows.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski I myself don't even have any Java experience! But anyway, a non-programmer would possibly think a `File` is a file, no?