# Can't find .nomedia "folder"

Tags: file-management, troubleshooting, hidden

I have a lot of folders that I wanted to hide, so I placed a `.nomedia` file in folder. I accidentally renamed a folder name to `.nomedia.` and BOOM all the folders including all images are hidden.

I tried "show hidden files" in file explorer/manager, Even ES file explorer can't find it. Images inside folder are in gallery (but not visible `File format not supported or files are corrupted`) and images location path are there but there is nothing.

I am pretty sure that I didn't deleted that folder(well at least I think, images are still in gallery but not visible), so I think my folder is just hidden.

How can I see the  hidden folder and images?

Comment: Related [Can .nomedia be a folder](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205240/131553)

Comment: I tried Az scanner but i still cant find that folder. Is it possible that folder is deleted, but images are still showing?

Comment: `find /sdcard/ -name .nomedia -type d`

Comment: sorry I don't understand,

Comment: image local path is "Internal storage/new/private/new/ images.jpeg" something like this, where first "new" is main folder that's hidden now accidentally and "private" and others are subfolder. images and local path are still in phone means folder is still there but hidden, right? when I click on local path it open in file manager but there is nothing like I said before.

Comment: Use [`find`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command in Termux app or `adb shell` to search files / directories by name, partial name, type, modification date and many other parameters. Use [`mv`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) command to rename the directory after it's found. Do a web search if you need help with commandline interface.

Comment: @Irfan Latif I tried that but can't find folder and I am able to create new folder that doesn't ask for replacing, so I think my folder is deleted. :(  thanks for help